# Login in the archive ascx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ascx

My code doesn't work and I don't know it. I tried very very times, but it doesn't work.

Sorry for dumb question

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoginUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="ControleBU.Views.Paginas.LoginUserControl" %>

<%
    <asp:Login runat="server"></asp:Login>
    <asp:LoginName runat="server"></asp:LoginName>
    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server"></asp:LoginStatus>
    <asp:LoginView runat="server"></asp:LoginView>            
%>
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean by your code doesn't work? What specific error you getting?

Comment: I just want insert loginStatus, login, loginName on archive ascx, but always it have error. Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.

Comment: I do not know how to use the component toolbox (login, LoginStatus) in an ascx file